# String Equivalence/Comparison in Python

Tags: python, string, file, if-statement, string-comparison

I can't seem to compare strings properly in python, what is the correct way to compare it in the if condition?

```
Testfile = "test.txt"
with open(TestFile) as testSet:
    line = testSet.read().rstrip('\n')
    if "#*#*# ham" or "#*#*# spam" in line: 
        print line
```

My test.txt something like looks like this:

```
#*#*# ham
foo bar bar foo bar bar bar bar
#*#*# ham
foo bar bar foo bar foo bar foo foo bar bar
#*#*# spam
foo bar foo foo bar barfoo bar foo foo bar bar
#*#*# spam
foo bar foo foo bar bar  foo foo bar bar
#*#*# ham
foo bar foo foo
#*#*# spam
foo bar foo foo bar bar  foo foo bar bar
#*#*# spam
bar foo bar foo foo bar 
#*#*# spam
bar bar foo foo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
Testfile = "test.txt"
with open(TestFile) as testSet:
    for line in testSet:
        line = line.strip() 
        if "#*#*# ham" in line or "#*#*# spam" in line: 
            print line
```

instead of what you are doing. You are reading the whole file into the line variable, the way your code is.

Comment: Then what exactly does `testSet.read()` and `testSet.readline()` do?

Comment: @Corbin, i meant to say will it make a difference if i use readline() instead of read()?

Comment: @2er0: As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects) tells you, the `read` method reads and returns the entire contents of the file. What did you think it did? (`readline` reads and returns a single line, but still you don't need to use it explicitly because you can and should use an iterator as in the code sample in this answer.)

Answer (score 2):

That's being read as:

```
if ("#*#*# ham") or ("#*#*# spam" in line):
```

And the string is being cast to true.

Try:

```
if "#*#*# ham" in line or "#*#*# spam" in line:
```

Comment: that condition prints out the `foo bar` text lines too

Comment: the `if "#*#*# ham" in line or "#*#*# spam" in line:` condition ends up as always true.

Comment: Just tested it, and I should have caught this before...  As jsbueno says, you have your entire file content in line, not individual lines.

Answer (score 0):

That should read:

```
testfile = "test.txt"
with open(testFile) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if "#*#*# ham" in line or "#*#*# spam" in line: 
            print line
```

Another nice form is:

```
if any(substr in line for substr in (#*#*# ham", "#*#*# spam")):
    print line
```

Comment: even the `any(substr in line for substr in (#*#*# ham", "#*#*# spam")):` condition ends up as always true. It prints out the `foo bar` lines

Comment: @2er0, because `line` contains the entire file, not one line.  See the `read` documentation.